# Sorting strings alphabetically without arrays in java

Tags: java, sorting, conditional-statements

So for this program I need to obtain three strings from a user and sort those strings alphabetically. The caveat is that I cannot use arrays. Also if the string does not start with an alphabetic letter than it is not accepted. So far I have managed to get the three strings from the user and am able to determine if they should be accepted on or not. What I can't figure out is how to sort them alphabetically. The main issue I am having is ignoring the strings that weren't accepted when sorting.  Here is the code to get the strings from the user.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please input the first name: ");
    String name1 = scan.nextLine();
    name1 = name1.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name1.substring(1,name1.length()).toLowerCase();
    if (name1.charAt(0) >= 'A' && name1.charAt(0) <= 'Z' ){
        System.out.println("The first name is: " + name1);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error: The name was not accepted");
        name1 = null;
    }

    System.out.print("Please input the second name: ");
    String name2 = scan.nextLine();
    name2 = name2.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name2.substring(1,name2.length()).toLowerCase();
    if (name2.charAt(0) >= 'A' && name2.charAt(0) <= 'Z'){
        System.out.println("The second name is: " + name2);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error: The name was not accepted");
        name2 = null;
    }

    System.out.print("Please input the third name: ");
    String name3 = scan.nextLine();
    name3 = name3.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name3.substring(1,name3.length()).toLowerCase();
    if (name3.charAt(0) >= 'A' && name3.charAt(0) <= 'Z'){
        System.out.println("The third name is: " + name3);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error: The name was not accepted");
        name3 = null;
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you use arrays? `Arrays.sort` is a great and simple way to do sorting...

Comment: Because homework. To be fair, this isn't a case of "do my homework for me."

Comment: Given the silly requirement, I'd probably build up a single, massive string that's `(<strlen in hex>data)*`, then rebuild it each time and do an insertion sort.

Comment: Hint:  There are a very limited number of possible orderings -- ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA.

Comment: Try comparing the first letters of each string and then sorting them based on the letters.

Comment: Another hint: Build a loop around each name input block, so you loop and try again if the name isn't accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution. It is a nightmare in readability to write this code without an array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameSort {

  private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void nameStort() {
    String name1 = readName("first");
    String name2 = readName("second");
    String name3 = readName("third");

    String potentialName1 = null;
    String potentialName2 = null;
    String potentialName3 = null;
    String potentialName4 = null;
    String potentialName5 = null;
    String potentialName6 = null;
    String potentialName7 = null;

    if (name1 == null) {
      if (name2 == null) {
        potentialName4 = name3;
      } else {
        potentialName4 = name2;
        if (name3 != null) {
          if (name2.compareTo(name3) > 0) {
            potentialName2 = name3;
          } else {
            potentialName6 = name3;
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      potentialName4 = name1;
      if (name2 == null) {
        if (name3 != null) {
          if (name1.compareTo(name3) > 0) {
            potentialName2 = name3;
          } else {
            potentialName6 = name3;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (name1.compareTo(name2) > 0) {
          potentialName2 = name2;
        } else {
          potentialName6 = name2;
        }
        if (name3 != null) {
          if (name1.compareTo(name3) > 0) {
            if (name2.compareTo(name3) > 0) {
              potentialName1 = name3;
            } else {
              potentialName3 = name3;
            }
          } else {
            if (name2.compareTo(name3) > 0) {
              potentialName5 = name3;
            } else {
              potentialName7 = name3;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The sorted names are: ");
    printIfNotNull(potentialName1);
    printIfNotNull(potentialName2);
    printIfNotNull(potentialName3);
    printIfNotNull(potentialName4);
    printIfNotNull(potentialName5);
    printIfNotNull(potentialName6);
    printIfNotNull(potentialName7);
  }

  private static void printIfNotNull(String potentialName) {
    if (potentialName != null) {
      System.out.println(potentialName);
    }
  }

  public static String readName(String position) {
    System.out.print("Please input the " + position + " name: ");
    String name = toTitleCase(scan.nextLine().trim());
    if (!name.isEmpty() && Character.isLetter(name.charAt(0))) {
      System.out.println("The " + position + " name is: " + name);
      return name;
    } else {
      System.out.println("Error: The name was not accepted");
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static String toTitleCase(String word) {
    if (word.isEmpty()) {
      return word;
    }
    // one way to do it
    return word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    nameStort();
  }
}
```

But without the silly array or collection restriction in the assignment the code is much more readable:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameSort {

  private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void nameStort() {
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList(readName("first"), readName("second"), readName("third"));
    Collections.sort(names);
    for (String name : names) {
      printIfNotEmpty(name);
    }
  }

  private static void printIfNotEmpty(String name) {
    if (!name.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println(name);
    }
  }

  public static String readName(String position) {
    System.out.print("Please input the " + position + " name: ");
    String name = toTitleCase(scan.nextLine().trim());
    if (!name.isEmpty() && Character.isLetter(name.charAt(0))) {
      System.out.println("The " + position + " name is: " + name);
      return name;
    } else {
      System.out.println("Error: The name was not accepted");
    }
    return "";
  }

  public static String toTitleCase(String word) {
    if (word.isEmpty()) {
      return word;
    }
    // one way to do it
    return word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    nameStort();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this to complicated given the user's experience with java?

Comment: @MarGar Any solution to this absurd assignment will be too complicated, and even for some more experienced in java it will be hard to read for sure. Not sure how to get around it given the constraints of the problem though.

Comment: indeed. +1 and hopefully he is able to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I coded this using Array.sort but of course it must be infinitely more complicated because why not. I also can't use methods, besides java methods of course,  or really any actually code except conditional statements, loops, and variable declarations. Thanks for the help though, I think the best bet is to ignore the case of null strings because there really is no other way.

Comment: @user2590123 You can't can't use methods? Who is making these requirements and why? Not sure why they want to enforce horrible coding habits.

Comment: @nmore i can use the java methods like string.compareTo but as far as creating my own methods i can't. I am not allowed to because i haven't learned it yet supposedly.

Answer (score 0):

For any of those wondering here is my solution to this problem given the ridiculous constraints. 
    public class Assignment3 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //read names and return error if the name starts with a non-alphabetic character
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please input the first name: ");
    String name1 = scan.nextLine();
    name1 = name1.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name1.substring(1,name1.length()).toLowerCase();
    if (Character.isLetter(name1.charAt(0))){
        System.out.println("The first name is: " + name1);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error: The name was not accepted");
        name1 = "";
    }

    System.out.print("Please input the second name: ");
    String name2 = scan.nextLine();
    name2 = name2.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name2.substring(1,name2.length()).toLowerCase();
    if (Character.isLetter(name2.charAt(0))){
        System.out.println("The second name is: " + name2);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error: The name was not accepted");
        name2 = "";
    }

    System.out.print("Please input the third name: ");
    String name3 = scan.nextLine();
    name3 = name3.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name3.substring(1,name3.length()).toLowerCase();
    if (Character.isLetter(name3.charAt(0))){
        System.out.println("The third name is: " + name3);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error: The name was not accepted");
        name3 = "";
    }
    //Sort the names alphabetically
    String first = "";
    if(name1.compareTo(name2) <= 0 && name1.compareTo(name3) <= 0){
        first = name1;
    }else if (name2.compareTo(name3) <= 0 && name2.compareTo(name1) <= 0){
        first = name2;
    }else if (name3.compareTo(name1) <= 0 && name3.compareTo(name2) <=0){
        first = name3;
    }

    String middle = "";
    if (name1.compareTo(name2)*name1.compareTo(name3) <= 0){
        middle = name1;
    }else if (name2.compareTo(name1)*name2.compareTo(name3) <= 0){
        middle = name2;
    }else if (name3.compareTo(name2)*name3.compareTo(name1) <= 0){
        middle = name3;
    }

    String last = "";
    if(name1.compareTo(name2) >= 0 && name1.compareTo(name3) >= 0){
        last = name1;
    }else if (name2.compareTo(name3) >= 0 && name2.compareTo(name1) >= 0){
        last = name2;
    }else if (name3.compareTo(name1) >= 0 && name3.compareTo(name2) >=0){
        last = name3;
    }
    if(first.isEmpty() && middle.isEmpty()){
        System.out.printf("The only name is \"%s\" ", last);
    }else if(first.isEmpty()){
        System.out.printf("the names are \"%s\"and \"%s\" ",middle,last);
    }else{
        System.out.printf("the names are \"%s\", \"%s\", and \"%s\" ",first,middle,last);
    }
}
```

}