# Tip Calculator Help in Java?

Tags: java, calculator, drjava

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TipCalc
{
public static void main(String[] args);
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
{
    System.out.println("Tip Calculator");
    System.out.println("===============");
    System.out.print("Enter check subtotal (9.25): ");
    double subtotal = cin.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter gratuity percentage (20): ");
    int gratuity = cin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    double gratuityAmount = gratuity * .01 * subTotal;
    System.out.println("\tGratuity: " + gratuityAmount);
    double total = gratuityAmount + subTotal;
    System.out.println("\tTotal: $" + total);
}
}
```

**I get these errors:** 3 errors found:
[line: 5]
**Error: missing method body, or declare abstract**
[line: 15]
**Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable subTotal
  location: class TipCalc**
[line: 17]
**Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable subTotal
  location: class TipCalc**
I just started to learn Java. I am confused on to what went wrong. Any advice?

Comment: Look at your `cin`. Where is it declared? Why is there a `;` after the `main` method declaration? Is it `subTotal` or `subtotal`?

Comment: Don't freak out at the first sign of a problem. Look at your book, look at your tutorials. Follow them closely.

Comment: `Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);` is declared between the method declaration and it's body, this isn't right

Comment: I appreciate all of your advice. Thank you all! I got it too work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main method lacks a body.

```
  public class TipCalc
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Tip Calculator");
      System.out.println("===============");
      System.out.print("Enter check subtotal (9.25): ");
      double subtotal = cin.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Enter gratuity percentage (20): ");
      int gratuity = cin.nextInt();
      System.out.println("");
      double gratuityAmount = gratuity * .01 * subTotal; //Note: subTotal variable isn't defined
      System.out.println("\tGratuity: " + gratuityAmount);
      double total = gratuityAmount + subTotal;
      System.out.println("\tTotal: $" + total);
    }
  }
```

That should help your formatting errors.

The method body comes immediately after such as: public void doSomething(){ <-begins body and ends with-> }

In the beginning, methods are only briefly discussed but you will go more in-depth and get the hang of it.

Comment: Is helping the very new frowned upon? I don't understand the down votes for hints or explanations. Please leave a constructive comment and explain the reasons an answer is wrong.

Comment: That worked for me, I forgot to define subTotal. I did, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @MarGar Just one friendly advice. Instead of doing others homework, please post up some hints. I do not think it is helpful for the OP who does not have enough experience :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Simply down voting answers with out feed back doesn't help those of us who are new to this site :) My redirects to places people could find the answers and hints have been down voted in the past by others so I thought this approach was more appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: @MarGar as I said it was friendly, so I do not have anything against you, but how do you think the op can improve his programming style, just by copying and pasting. It is simply **plagiarism**  and better **stealing**. May be there is no consequences for you, but I am sure there are so many bad consequences for the op. I am sure you do not want anybody to be in hot water. And I never seen anybody to vote anybody down by just pointing out hints.

Comment: No, I really do appreciate the feedback. My thanks was genuine :). I was referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924445/sorting-strings-alphabetically-without-arrays-in-java/25924619#25924619 where a simple link to the String class and reference to using `compareTo()` in order to sort Strings alphabetically was down voted. I am still trying to understand the proper format.

Comment: @MarGar no he or she added more info again giving the code answer is not helpful for the op :)

Answer (score 1):

Every Java application must contain the following structure

```
class NameOfYourClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

All codes that needs to be ran by `JVM` will go inside following block:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
           all your codes go here
        }
```

Hope this hint can help you to solve your issue

Source: [read about the main method](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/getStarted/application/main.html)